# Windows Phone 7 after ios developement

Tags: windows-phone-7, ios5

This might sound a bit of the topic, but i really wanna know whether it is a good idea to learn windows phone 7 development after ios development. I am still learning ios, but of the basic stuff is covered. So I was thinking to start windows 7 development side by side.

So is it a good idea?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit off-topic.  Apart from not actually being a software development question, how are we supposed to know your full experience and business plans for the future? W8 is comiing out, anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames : i know c#, objective c and c++. Plus it isnt bout any business, its more bout learning new things. So will it be a good idea to go for w7 or some other language?

Comment: If you have free time, why not to learn something new, and got some extra experience?

Comment: n by something new, which technology are u talking bout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a good idea. First, you only not learn about the partial framework of the .NET world and you are scoped with the available namespaces you will use in Windows Phone 7/8.

Once you start learning Windows Phone 7, it should be easy for you to switch to another Framework Class Library (FCL) that is Silverlight that can be use to develop applications in a web browser, then switch to WPF which is use to develop desktop applications.

You will not only start in my honest opinion with Windows Phone 7 development but you will also start learning applying design patterns just by developing simple applications to the phone. Once you are comfortable with it, it should be easy for you to apply the advance stuff when it comes to Silverlight and WPF.

Pretty much as a developer, you should not be hesitant to learn, relearn, and unlearn. This is the 21st century. Everything change so fast.